# Can you use google app engine as the serverside solution for an android mobile app

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I have an android app that I want to connect with a server (and database) to store persistent data.  Can I use the google App engine to provide this functionality including account verification?  As you might have guessed - I'm not a web programmer, however I want to choose the right direction.

To be clearer - I want to use the server to proivde a set of web services with read/write access to the data stored in the datastore

cheers,
Anton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely yes. Here are some links to get you started:

1. [Creating an App Engine Connected Android Project](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae).
2. [Google I/O 2011: Android + App Engine: A Developer's Dream Combination](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7SxNNC429U) - a YouTube video.

Comment: P.S. You can also look at the list of related question (on the right) kindly provided by StackOverflow :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think so, personally I use an googleAppEngine web app as a Be for ACRA (Application crash report for android).

check http://code.google.com/p/acra-reporter/.

If you download the sender (which is the android side) you have an example on how to interact with an google app engine be over http.

Hope this helps :)